# SSL Issue only in Google Chrome

Tags: iis, google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am having an SSL issue, but it only appears to be happening in Google Chrome.

I've checked with Firefox, Safari and Internet Explorer and there fine.

Does anyone know what is wrong? I've tried it on a BLANK page and Chrome still says there is an issue. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be referring to content that does not belong to your domain (ex. images) and that are retrieve from another location on the internet.

Since the browser has to get them via a http:// request on the other site, it warns you that all the content does not come from your website overs the SSL connection.

Did you tried the blank page after accessing another page of your site? Or just after launching chrome?

Comment: Hi, it was after accessing another page. But even if I go to it directly, it still says there's an issue.

Comment: Looking further into it, IE is saying "The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority." - But I've installed all the files Thawte gave me!

Comment: Your certificate must be register to your site with your IIS. It must also match the domain name you are hosting. Take care to serve the public certificate. Check also that the root certificate from whom the certificate is issued, belongs to your browser root authorities list.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this exact problem and solved it this morning. Two things:

1. Clear Google Chromes's browser cache data
2. Make sure your app doesn't have references to external resources that is none-https

Hope this helps,
Ray.